# erlang crash dump no more index entries

Tags: erlang, crash-dumps

i have a problem about erlang.
One of my Erlang node crashes, and generates erl_crash.dump with reason **no more index entries in atom_tab (max=1048576)**.
i checked the dump file and i found that there are a lot of atoms in the form of **'B\2209\000...**, (about 1000000 entries)

```
=proc:<0.11744.7038>
State: Waiting
Name: 'B\2209\000d\022D.
Spawned as: proc_lib:init_p/5
Spawned by: <0.5032.0>
Started: Sun Feb 23 05:23:27 2014
Message queue length: 0
Number of heap fragments: 0
Heap fragment data: 0
Reductions: 1992
Stack+heap: 1597
OldHeap: 1597
Heap unused: 918
OldHeap unused: 376
Program counter: 0x0000000001eb7700 (gen_fsm:loop/7 + 140)
CP: 0x0000000000000000 (invalid)
arity = 0
```

do you have some experience about what they are?

Comment: The information in the trace says that the process with Pid `<0.11744.7038>` is registered as `'B\2209\000d\022D`, that it has a gen_fsm behavior, and that it was created by a spawn or spawn_link or spawn_monitor (M,F,A) call. This should help you to find it in the code. Also the Pid value indicates that there was a huge amount of processes started in the VM. This could mean that you have a lot of parallel processes, or that there are a lot of retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it tells you, that you generate atoms. There is somewhere `list_to_atom/1` which is called with variable argument. Because you have process with this sort of name, you `register/2` processes with this name. It is may be your code or some third party module what you use. It's bad behavior. Don't do that and don't use modules which is doing it.

To be honest, I can imagine design where I would do it intentionally but it is very special case and it is obviously not the case when you ask this question.

Comment: no no no, there is not such name as ''B\2209\000d\022D.' in my code, and there is no 3rd part code. i guess it has some special meaning in erl_crash.dump.

Comment: @ruanhao: I don't claim anything like this. I wrote, you do `list_to_atom/1` somewhere in your code.

Comment: thank you man, you are right, there is something wrong in my code, like "register([x,x,x,x,x], self())", which causes the crash and i amazingly did not find it.

Comment: @ruanhao: It's weird. This code should raise `badarg` error.

Comment: it is register(list_to_atom([x,x,x,x]), self()), that is why i ran out of atom index.

Comment: It makes sense now. Grepping code for `list_to_atom/1` is the key.

Answer (score 3):

> Atoms
>       By default, the maximum number of atoms is 1048576. This limit can be raised or lowered using the +t option.
>
> Note: an atom refers into an atom table which also consumes memory. The atom text is stored once for each unique atom in this table. The atom table is not garbage-collected.

I think that you produce a lot of atom in your program, the number of atom reach the number limition for atom.

You can use this `+t` option to change the number limition of atom in your erlang VM when your start your erlang node.

Comment: yes, i did spawn a lot of process, but these processes are not registered, so they should not have a 'Name' i think. but why it has a weird name like "'B\2209\000d\022D."

Comment: you can read this link for erlang crash dump.http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html. from the doc `Name:` stands for the name of one process.